# Question Error Correcting Codes

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, niederreiter

Let $C$ be a code over the finite field $GF(2)$ with generator matrix $G$ and parity matrix $H$. Let $e+C=C'$ be a coset of code $C$. Let $S$ be a non-singular matrix and $H'=H\times S$. Finally, let $C''\subset C'$. Is there any efficient way of finding any other element of the coset $C'$ by **only** using $C''$ and $H'$ (with appropriate parameters for the code $C$)?

Comment: Do you want some structure on $C''$?  It could be empty.  Anyway, finding another element of the coset is equivalent to finding a non-zero vector in $\mathrm{Ker}\ G = \mathrm{Img}\ H = \mathrm{Img}\ H\times S$, which is trivial.

Comment: @DavidCash Why finding another element of the coset is equivalent to finding ...?. Recall that $e$ is an fixed element. Here an example in SAGE
H = matrix(GF(2),[[1,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1]]);
Krnl = H.right_kernel();
G = Krnl.basis_matrix();
S = matrix(GF(2),[[1,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0]])
SH= S*H
m=vector(GF(2),[0,0,1]);
m1=vector(GF(2),[1,0,1,1]);
e=vector(GF(2),[0,1,0,0,0,0,0])
print 'm*G+e=',(m*G+e),'sindrome',H*((m*G+e))
print 'm1*SH=',(m1*SH),'sindrome',H*((m1*SH))

Comment: in the last example (SAGE) m1 is a non-zero vetor in Ker G and that not belong to the same coset $C+e$.

Comment: I meant in $\mathrm{Img}\ G$ (typo).

Comment: @DavidCash I understand,

Comment: @DavidCash Is there any way of hidden the coset?